# How to use webclient in spring webflux to download pdf file in a rest api

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a rest api which will download pdf file from a website and then return the pdf file to the caller.

Using the following code, I can get `Mono<ClientResponse>` from the api:

```
Mono<ClientResponse> requestSpec1 = WebClient
            .create()
            .method(HttpMethod.GET)
            .uri("<url>")
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF)
            .exchange();
```

However, if I tried to get `ClientResponse` from `requestSpec1` using `block()` method, I got an exception said **ClientResponse block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread...**

Can anyone help the case please.

Comment: Please post that part of code where you are blocking it thats causing the issue

Comment: @Barath ClientResponse response = requestSpec1.block();

Comment: Ideally you want it to be non blocking. Any reason you want to block it ?. Also can you try chaining block ```.exchange().block()```. Also some nice suggestion here [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48517762/can-i-use-block-method-of-flux-returned-from-spring5s-webclient). Provide your full code, it looks like you are directly invoking block on main thread.

Comment: I use `block()` method to get the `ClientResponse` object and then I can get pdf file name, file body etc from it. I don't know how to get there info without `block()` method and it is my question.

Comment: you can use ```.exchange().flatmap()``` and then handle what you want to do with it.

Comment: I got it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're trying to call `block()` on the response in the middle of a reactive pipeline. Without more details or a code snippet, I can only assume you're doing that in the middle of a reactive Controller method.

As of Reactor Core 3.2.0, [blocking inside a Thread that belongs to a `Scheduler` will thrown an exception like this](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/1102). You should instead try to write a complete reactive pipeline and chain operators like, in this case, `map` or `flatMap`.